# Properties from properties file are not used, when run jmeter test in NON GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I am using two .properties files for two various environments
I got Property File Reader with path defined as:

> D:/path_to_file/${env}.properties

properties files contain:

```
host: ip_value
port: port_value
```

I use these two values in endpoint of my HTTP header manager - used as ${host}:${port}

In User defined variables I got:

```
host    ${__P(host)}    
port    ${__P(port)}    
env     ${__P(env,default_env)}
```

I run the test from cmd:

> jmeter -n -t D:/path_to_test/test.jmx -Jenv=my_env

When I ran this in GUI mode, the correct values are loaded from .properties file

When I run it from CLI, then 1:1 is used instead of my defined values. But logs say, that the properties file was found and loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what "Property File Reader" is, it might be the case it is something which is being initialized **after** the User Defined Variables, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

Also pay attention to [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) or JMeter Test Elements

You don't need any external tools in order to read the external properties file, there is [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) which allows "feeding" arbitrary .properties file to JMeter on top of "normal" [*jmeter.properties* and *user.properties*](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) files and the values passed via `-J` option

> -q, --addprop 
> additional JMeter property file(s)

Comment: yes, I can use jmeter -q D:\path_to_file\my_env.properties, and just change my_env value for various files, but the other way was prettier to me. I will try that way, that you suggested. thanks